# How can I go about reading this multidimensional array in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, multidimensional-array

I have this array which is use to store some minor data on 'blocks' in swift.

I used to have three dictionarys called blockNames, blockTypes and blockImages. However, I wanted to keep everything in one place. I wanted to use the format as followed, but I assumes I could just read it like; `blockData[0.0]["image"]` to get the image for block 0.0. However it defines the arrays as Doubles and the dictionaries within them as NSObjects.

This is the array I an talking about

```
let blockData = [
    // ===== 0.0 - Air =====
    0.0:[
        "name":"Air",
        "image":"0.0.png",
        "type":"custom"
    ],
    0.1:[
        "name":"barrier",
        "image":"barrier",
        "type":"custom"
    ],
    // ===== 1.0 - Dirt =====
    1.0:[
        "name":"Dirt - Center",
        "image":"1.0.png",
        "type":"solid"
    ],
    1.1:[
        "name":"Dirt width Grass - Center",
        "image":"1.1.png",
        "type":"solid"
    ],
    1.2:[
        "name":"Dirt width Grass - Left",
        "image":"1.2.png",
        "type":"solid"
    ],
    1.3:[
        "name":"Dirt width Grass - Right",
        "image":"1.3.png",
        "type":"solid"
    ],
    1.4:[
        "name":"Dirt - Left",
        "image":"1.4.png",
        "type":"solid"
    ],
    1.5:[
        "name":"Dirt - Right",
        "image":"1.5.png",
        "type":"solid"
    ],
    1.6:[
        "name":"Dirt with Flat Top - Center",
        "image":"1.6.png",
        "type":"solid"
    ],
    1.7:[
        "name":"Dirt with Flat Top - Left",
        "image":"1.7.png",
        "type":"solid"
    ],
    1.8:[
        "name":"Dirt with Flat Top - Right",
        "image":"1.8.png",
        "type":"solid"
    ],
    1.9:[
        "name":"Dirt - Center",
        "image":"1.9.png",
        "type":"solid"
    ],
    1.11:[
        "name":"Dirt - Bottom Center",
        "image":"1.11.png",
        "type":"solid"
    ],
    ...
    ]
```

I would like to read the array like follows;

```
let blockID: CGFloat = 0.0

let blockType = blockData[Float(blockID)]["type"]
```

Thank you.

Comment: If elements aren't identified by position, it isn't an array.

Comment: @ScottHunter I believe OP comes from PhP where (ordered) dictionaries are called arrays (it's weird I know)

Comment: @Kametrixom In answer to your comment, I do come from PHP. However, Do you know a way to declare the dictionary as String:String instead of NSObject?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you will get an optional in return from your `blockData[0.0]`.
You will need to unwrap that optional either using an `if let` statement or force unwrap.

```
let blockData = [
    // ===== 0.0 - Air =====
    0.0:[
        "name":"Air",
        "image":"0.0.png",
        "type":"custom"
    ],
    0.1:[
        "name":"barrier",
        "image":"barrier",
        "type":"custom"
    ],
    // ===== 1.0 - Dirt =====
    1.0:[
        "name":"Dirt - Center",
        "image":"1.0.png",
        "type":"solid"
    ],
    1.1:[
        "name":"Dirt width Grass - Center",
        "image":"1.1.png",
        "type":"solid"
    ],
    1.2:[
        "name":"Dirt width Grass - Left",
        "image":"1.2.png",
        "type":"solid"
    ]
]

blockData[0.0]!["type"]
```

works perfectly fine in swift 2.0

Comment: The declaration of the array seems to be [Double:NSObject] so I can't get the dictionary with a string. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Type cast your NSObject `if let data = blockData[0.0] as? [String:String]`

Comment: Is there a way to cast this in the first decleraton?

Comment: I have a problem, as I am using floats '1.1, 1.2' as the variables I cannot use doubles to get the data. Is there a way round this?